# Magento 1.9 Missing products

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have imported 16990 products to my website via Import All products Profile

Its divided info 9 files

8 files contains 2000 products 
and 1 file contains 990 products

All files imported successfully with no error messages

After checking the total number of records from catalog, about **1500 products are Missing**

I have double check the CSVs files its correct with no issues

Could you please help me to explorer the issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have prepared a workaround for this problem. First of all, check if your missing products are showing in the database. If yes, try to do the following:

- Sign in to Magento Admin Panel
- Go to Catalog > Manage Products

Your current URL will look like this:

> yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/index/key/[your_key]/

Change your URL to:

> yourdomain.com/index.php/admin/catalog_product/edit/id/[product_id]/key/[your_key]/

You can find the product_id in the database. When you enter this URL, you will be able to edit the product. Now, check product attributes and make sure that you check all the values which are empty or not filled properly. In this way, you can clearly see all little mistakes by the Values in the CSV.

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

The issue is solved. The problem was in Categories setting Is_Anchor is set to NO in Sub-Category while the Parent Category is YES 

Furthermore, the default Category Is_Anchor set to NO 

After change Is_Anchor to Yes To All Categories: default category,  Parent Category and Sub-Category, and re-uploading the files without any change the counts is correct and issue is solved !

Comment: @Sumayah Awesome! If you need any Magento related help further, I would advise you to post your query at magento.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and replay